# How to solve the differential equation $yy'=Ax+Byx^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How do I solve this differential equation $yy'=Ax+Byx^2$?

I have tried so many times but it seems that it is not the type which has been introduced in any textbook about differential equation.
An approximate solution is also acceptable if it doesn't have closed-form solution.

Comment: "I have tried so many times"

Better to just put what you tried.

Comment: Another improvement to the Question might be to explain what interests you in solving this kind of differential equation.

Comment: @idk  What I tried is just to check it to see whether it is exact equation and BernoulIi equation as well as the methods of solving anonymous equation,etc.

Comment: Abel equation of the second kind

Comment: $t=\dfrac{Bx^3}{3}\to yy'=y+\dfrac{A}{\sqrt[3]{3B^2t}}$

Answer (score 1):

This differential equation does not appear to have closed-form solutions.  Are you sure the question asks you to solve it?

EDIT: Maple calls this an Abel equation of the second kind, class A.  These do not have closed form solutions in general.  In particular, Maple, finds no symmetries for your equation.

Comment: Really? In fact, this equation comes from vibration problems in physics. Its original form is   
                        x''=Ax+Bx'x^2
where x is the displacement. B is a very small quantity. So an approximate solution is also acceptable.

Comment: You could get a solution as a series in powers of $B$: $y(x) = \sqrt{Ax^2+c} + B y_1 + B^2 y_2 + \ldots$ where $y_1, y_2, \ldots$ are obtained by solving first-order linear differential equations.

Comment: I assume that $y=\sqrt {A}x+By_1$ After aubstituting it into the eqution to be solved, I get a more complex one which also seems unsolvable

Comment: Write $y = \sqrt{A} x + B y_1$, and the equation becomes
$$ (\sqrt{A} x +  B y_1)(\sqrt{A}+ B y_1') = A x + B \sqrt{A} x^3 + B^2 y_1 x^2$$
Expand.  Note the terms with no $B$ cancel.  The coefficients of $B$ give you the equation $$\sqrt{A} y_1  + \sqrt{A} x y_1' = \sqrt{A}  x^3 $$
which is easy to solve.  Similarly (but more complicated) for higher order terms.